# Deleting a temp table based on a string value?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is there a way in sql server 2008 to delete #tt using a string:

```
delete temp table with name = 'tt'
```

edit: what would really be nice if there was a function like: getString(#tt) that returned 'tt'

Comment: what?, can you clarify what you want?

Comment: Let's say I have a temp table named #tt.  Is there a way I can delete it if I only have the string 'tt' at my disposal without creating an if statement with: if(string = 'tt') then delete table #tt

Comment: I think you need to use dynamic sql for that

Comment: Are you aware that a #temp table (not ##global mind you) is deleted as soon as the stored procedure calling it exits.  Is this not good enough for you?

Comment: Can you explain why you think you need to drop a #temp table that has been created in some way that prevents your script from knowing what it's called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with dynamic SQL:

```
EXEC('DROP TABLE #' + @MyTempTable)
```

If you go this route I would give [this article](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) a good read to get an understanding of the pros and cons of dynamic sql.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can do this with dynamic SQL, I'm not sure how you are going to **create** varying temp tables in a parent session scope with non-dynamic SQL and then use dynamic SQL within a child session scope.

Can you give an example of what you are doing to create the tables and where you want them to be dropped?